# How to use the `reply` parameter in the gRPC UnaryClientInterceptor?

Tags: go, interceptor, grpc-go

The [`UnaryClientInterceptor`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc#UnaryClientInterceptor) interface from `google.golang.org/grpc` has a signature like

```
type UnaryClientInterceptor func(ctx context.Context, method string, req, reply any, cc *ClientConn, invoker UnaryInvoker, opts ...CallOption) error
```

My understanding of this interface is that implementations are called before the request is made, allowing for the enrichment and modification of the request before it hits the network.

I don't, however, understand the `reply` parameter since the request hasn't been made yet. Am I misunderstanding the use of this interface or are there interesting things that can be done with the `reply` parameter even given that we can't actually access the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inspect the response within the `reply` argument after the gRPC call is made.

One of the arguments of the unary interceptor is the `invoker` function, which has type [`UnaryInvoker`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc#UnaryInvoker). Within the unary interceptor, you are supposed to call this function, as mentioned in the docs:

> invoker is the handler to complete the RPC and it is the responsibility of the interceptor to call it

And `invoker` itself takes `req` and `reply` as arguments. You can call the invoker *and then* inspect `reply`.

**But, how to inspect it?** The dynamic type of the `reply` interface is supposed to be a pointer to the return type of your gRPC handler as defined in your protobuffer schema. You can inspect the value of `method` to know what return type to expect.

To understand this better, you can take a look at the code generated by `protoc`. The implementation of a gRPC method shows what are the actual arguments used to call `Invoke`.

Let's say you have a protobuffer like:

```
package foo;

service MyService {
    rpc GetFoo(FooRequest) returns (FooResponse);
}
```

The generated code for the `GetFoo` method will look like:

```
func (c *myServiceClient) GetFoo(ctx context.Context, in *FooRequest, opts ...grpc.CallOption) (*FooResponse, error) {
    out := new(FooResponse)
    err := c.cc.Invoke(ctx, "/foo.MyService/GetFoo", in, out, opts...)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return out, nil
}
```

Therefore you know the type of `reply` based on the value of `method`. From then, you can obtain the following example unary interceptor:

```
grpc.WithUnaryInterceptor(func(ctx context.Context, method string, req, reply any, cc *grpc.ClientConn, invoker grpc.UnaryInvoker, opts ...grpc.CallOption) error {
    // some interceptor logic
    // ...
    // then you must call invoker
    err := invoker(ctx, method, req, reply, cc, opts...)
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
    }
    // finally you can inspect reply before returning
    switch method {
    case "/foo.MyService/GetFoo":
        fooResp := reply.(*FooResponse)
        // access fields to do whatever you want

    // other switch cases as needed
    }
    return nil
}),
```

Comment: Thank you! Very interesting that the `reply` becomes valid after the call is made. I know that this isn't really part of the question but are you aware of any docs that make this clear?

Comment: I don’t remember any that says this. I guess it was only vaguely implied